# Django : request.POST error "__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python, django

I have a simple form in my Django project:

**forms.py**

```
class DamageListCriteria(forms.Form):
    fromdate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}))
    todate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}))

class Meta:
    fields = ['fromdate','todate']
```

**views.py**

```
class DamageListCriteria(TemplateView):
template_name = "damage/damagelist_criteria.html"

def get(self, request):
    form = DamageListCriteria()
    general = General.objects.get(pk=1)
    args = {
        'form': form,
        'general': general
    }
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)

def post(self, request):
    general = General.objects.get(pk=1)
    form = DamageListCriteria(request.POST)

    args = {
           'form': form,
           'general': general
           }
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'damage/list/criteria/$', views.DamageListCriteria.as_view(), name="damage-list-criteria"),
```

when I try to post I am getting this error :
**'__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'**

the error is on the **form = DamageListCriteria(request.POST)**  line of code.

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because **you defined your form class and view class with the same name**. So change the class name of either view or form class.

or change your respective files as below,

**`forms.py`**(Changed form class name to `DamageListCriteriaForm`)

```
class DamageListCriteriaForm(forms.Form):
    fromdate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}))
    todate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}))

    class Meta:
        fields = ['fromdate', 'todate']
```

**`views.py`** (changed the references of form class)

```
class DamageListCriteria(TemplateView):
    template_name = "damage/damagelist_criteria.html"

    def get(self, request):
        form = DamageListCriteriaForm()
        general = General.objects.get(pk=1)
        args = {
            'form': form,
            'general': general
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        general = General.objects.get(pk=1)
        form = DamageListCriteriaForm(request.POST)

        args = {
            'form': form,
            'general': general
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You redefined your `DamageListCriteria` class in `views.py`. So, you're trying to instantiate your view class, instead of form.

Try changing your view name to `DamageListCriteriaView`, or/and form to `DamageListCriteriaForm`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Sorry , I can't accept as answer because someone post the same answer first